# Avoid to display Emoji with Unicode 1.1 (html)

Tags: html, unicode, emoji

I try to add an Emoji (♥) to my HTML Code and show it with Chrome.

```
<p>&#x2665;</p>
```

The heart is showing by the old Unicode Version 1.1 and because of that it is black:

[image]

How can i add the Emoji and show it in this new version?

[image]

Comment: Google about custom fonts in CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code point for that emoji is `U+2764 — HEAVY BLACK HEART`. The ‘black’ refers to pre-emoji times, when this character was filled up (instead of only an outline).

You can append `U+FE0F — VARIATION SELECTOR-16` to explicitly specify the colored version. `U+FE0E` will specify black/white:

- U+2764: ❤
- U+2764, U+FE0E: ❤︎
- U+2764, U+FE0F: ❤️

The results are probably browser and system dependent, and dependent on what fonts are used. For me (Firefox / Windows 10) the first two above are black, while the third one is red.

Comment: On my device, all of those hearts are red, both in the StackOverflow app and in the web browser (both mobile and desktop modes).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose it depends from the font you are using. You should find a webfont that is containing the emoji in the style you want and apply it to your page.

If you do not know web fonts take a look to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts

Comment: From a fast research I found a blog post that could help you https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2014/12/how-to-use-system-emoji-with-webfonts/